# Is it possible to query on nested map on firestore where the key is a domain?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I have an **agency** collection in firestore where along with other data, I am also storing domains that are owned by the agency. There could be multiple such domains.

Ex -

```
domains: {
    sub.domain.com: {
      active: true,
      date_added: timestamp
    },
    anotherSub.domain.com: {
      active: false,
      date_added: timestamp
    }
  },
  name: "Agency Name"
```

With this data I want to develop a functionality to **search for the agency name** based on the domain (only if in acrive state).

Ex -

> searching with **sub.domain.com** should give me **"Agency Name"**

I am using where condition to search this but I am not able to retrieve any documents and i suppose that is because firestore would be converting the dot(.) of domain as the nested object while performing the search.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`FieldPath` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.fieldpath) to wrap the field names and prevent Firestore from parsing the dots in them as nested fields.

E.g. (not tested code):

```
where(FieldPath('sub.domain.com', 'active'), '==', true)
```